# Prove trigonometric identity and how to have ideas

Tags: trigonometry

This is the identity:

$$\cos^2(a)-\cos^2(b)=\frac{\tan^2(b)-\tan^2(a)}{(1+\tan^2(a))\cdot(1+\tan^2(b))}$$

What I would do:

1)Try divide the left-hand by 1

2)Trying thy other way from right-hand to left-hand

Those two ideas don't help me.
So how to have ideas and be sure that those ideas are the right ones or do I have to try everything that cames at my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from the Pythagorean Theorem:
$$cos^2x+sin^2x=1$$
Then dividing this by $cos^2x$ we have:
$$1+tan^2x= sec^2x$$
Now let's look at the LHS:
$$cos^2a-cos^2b= cos^2acos^2b(\frac{1}{cos^2b}-\frac{1}{cos^2a})$$
$$=\frac{1}{sec^2asec^2b}(sec^2b-sec^2a)$$
From earlier we know how to substitute $sec^2x$ and have
$$=\frac{1}{(1+tan^2a)(1+tan^2b)}(1+tan^2b)-(1+tan^2a)$$
Or simplified:
$$\frac{tan^2b-tan^2a}{(1+tan^2a)(1+tan^2b)}$$
The identities often revert back to P.T. at some point and is often a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the only way to get better at solving these types of problems is to get more experience. In time, you'll start to notice patterns with mulch more ease. Here, you should start by looking at the right side and figuring out if anything can be simplified (you should see that you're able to use an identity to simplify it directly).